# A variant form of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Suppose $u(t)$ is a measurable function on $[0,\infty)$ and satisfies $$0\le u(t) \le A + Bt\int_0^t u(s) ds$$ for all $t\ge 0$; here $A, B$ are positive constants. Is it possible to derive an upper bound for $u(t)$? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the additional assumption that $u$ is continuous, set $H(t)=\int^t_0u$, then
$$\dot{H}-BtH\leq A$$
and so,
$$
\Big(e^{-\tfrac{B}{2}t^2}H(t)\Big)'\leq A e^{-\tfrac{B}{2}t^2}
$$
Integrating both sides over $[0,t]$ gives

$$
H(t)\leq A e^{\tfrac{B}{2}t^2}\int^t_0e^{-\tfrac{B}{2}s^2}\,ds$$

and so,

$$
\begin{align}
u(t)\leq A+ BtH(t)&\leq A+ ABtA e^{\tfrac{B}{2}t^2}\int^t_0e^{-\tfrac{B}{2}s^2}\,ds\\
&\leq A  + ABt e^{\tfrac{B}{2}t^2}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\tfrac{B}{2\pi}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks! This is great.